# How can I load Ubuntu when all I have is Grub?

Tags: kernel, upgrade, grub2, wubi

So I have upgraded Ubuntu with the latest Kernel. But after the upgrade and after I rebooted Ubuntu, all I get is GRUB. How do I load Ubuntu again when all I have is GRUB?

I installed Ubuntu using wubi.

Thanks heaps for the help

Comment: Is this wubi installation or normal installation?

Comment: This is outdated I believe. Can somebody tell me how to do this on grub2?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Using Grub

If you get to a `grub` prompt and the system and kernel are still installed on the partition, you can "manually" boot the system - i.e. without the help of a working grub.cfg. This also works with a grub run from live media. To this end grub includes a rudimentary command ine, which you can use to find the partition and boot the system.

```
find /vmlinuz
```

This should give you the partition like (hd0,0). You can also use the `ls` command to poke around the partition and see which kernels are available. The `search` command works similarly. You can also use *tab completion*.

```
set root=(hd0,1)
```

Of course, replace the parition identifier with whatever `find` showed you.

```
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1
initrd /initrd.img
```

Select the kernel image and initrd image, a pair which always needs to be used together. Luckily Ubuntu creates a pair of symlinks in the root directory which point to a working image and initrd. Note that you need to replace `/dev/sda1` with a representation of the partition in the scheme used by the Linux kernel. Roughly, `(hd0,1)` corresponds to `/dev/sda1`; `(hd0,2) corresponds to`/dev/sda2`;`(hd1,1) corresponds to `/dev/sdb1`.

```
boot
```

This boots the selected kernel from the selected partition. Once you've managed to boot your system, you can use that to restore grub, as is detailed e.g. [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

## Grub with Wubi

The above was premised on the assumption that Ubuntu was installed regularly, i.e. in its own separate partition. As you write, you used Wubi, which means you installed it to a large *file* on a Windows (NTFS) partition using a technique called "Lupin". I see no reason why this couldn't work in principle, though the process is more complicated. Here's the content of a `grub.cfg` based on a Wubi install:

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set be300f9c300f5ab3
loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
set root=(loop0)
linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk
initrd /boot/initrd.img
```

You'll need to adapt this to your particular case. In this snippet, taken from a 10.10 install, the `search` command finds the root partition using a filesystem UUID or identifier, which you presumably don't know; you can use `--file --set /ubuntu/disks/root.disk` instead ([here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#search)'s the official documentation). This grub configuration creates a virtual disk - a "loopback device" - called `loop0` which represents the contents of the "partition file", `/ubuntu/disks/root.disk` on your NTFS partition. With a bit of trial and error, you should be able to make this work.

Comment: I get `error: unknown command find'.`

Comment: @Abdull - this is because you are using grub2 instead of legacy grub. Press Tab twice and see the available commands, or
pager=1 \\
help

Comment: If you are using EFI, replace `linux` and `initrd` with resp. `linuxefi` and `initrdefi`.