# "Warning! No such command: linux" at GRUB prompt

Tags: grub2, 12.10

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my computer (alongside Windows 7) from a live cd, but when I rebooted my computer after a successful installation, I get a `grub>` prompt. When I type `boot` in it, it prints

```
Error 8: Kernel must be loaded before booting
```

So I searched and I found [Loading Ubuntu From Grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21342/how-can-i-load-ubuntu-when-all-i-have-is-grub), but when I type `linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5` I get this message

```
Warning! No such command: linux
```

Does anybody have any idea about what I should do ?

Note that I reinstalled Ubuntu but still get the same issue, and that this is not my first time installing Ubuntu (I installed many versions a dozen times before and this is the first time I've faced this issue).

When I type : `kernel /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5` instead of : `linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5` I get `Error 15: File not found` (I also tried `sda4` since `find /vmlinuz` is printing `hd(0,4)`)

Comment: Normally I would recommend boot repair in this situation. However as the unanswered question is seven years old the OP has probably got system to boot by now. VTC as went away on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting from a livecd, chrooting into your ubuntu partition(s), and manually running '# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg'?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, When I do as you said, I get this error : **/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).**

Comment: You did not chroot into your ubuntu partition correctly.  First create a directory in /media (e.g `# mkdir /media/ubu`).  Then mount your ubuntu / partition into that directory (e.g `# mount /dev/sda1 /media/ubu` note that this example depends on which partition is mounted as / in ubuntu).  Then `# chroot /media/ubu`.  At this point, the grub command should work.

Comment: You have to find the right partition which not easy at beginner level. If you just installed it and you do not have data etc. you would need I would in your place install again. But why Ubuntu 12.04? Since the latest stable is over v19?