# Need to boot kernel

Tags: boot, 13.04, windows, kernel, windows-vista

Ok, I have no idea what I'm doing, and I'm a total newbie with the Ubuntu kernel and grub and whatnot. Right now, I have Ubuntu 13.04 installed on an external drive, and am trying to get it to boot on my laptop. Whenever I do it on my desktop, it works fine, but the laptop just brings up a grub 2 prompt. I googled for a while but came up with nothing at all. And, when I try to just type 'boot', it responds "error: you need to load the kernel first." any help is appreciated, bit if minimal techie speak is used, it would be even better!

Comment: Could you update question with laptop and PC hardware specs.?

Comment: Could you try and describe chronologically what you have done to get the stage you are at; in your question?

Answer (score -2):

So you did the installation on another computer and saved it to a external HDD, correct?  I haven't done this before, and can't find much relating to your question.  But have a read through [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21342/how-can-i-load-ubuntu-when-all-i-have-is-grub).  It may answer your question because it sounded like the user was having Ubuntu issues as well.

Also from reading, you may have to reinstall due to GRUB2 issues.  You can read the wiki documentation [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20from%20LiveCD)

But from what I can see just from looking around, there are a lot of issues wit installing Ubuntu on an external hard drive, and using it for multiple computers.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for your troubles, but theres no need to minus me when all I've done is try to answer your question.  I hope you have a terrible time fixing this and go through hell and back.

Comment: I feel you should remove your comment because it's only your _guess_ that the downvote was from the person who asked the question.

Comment: I almost want to downvote you just for your comment... How can you tell who downvoted you? What an attitude!