# Boot problem when trying to install linux over a flash drive

Tags: boot, grub2, usb-drive

When I first booted into my Ubuntu flash drive, it booted into something called "GNU GRUB", like this:

[image]

What is it, and how can I get Ubuntu working?

Comment: The screen shown above is the Grub shell. Is anything displayed before you see this screen?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should see first some entries with the available OS(s) listed
Anyway a short googling should give you a ot of explenations how to boot manually from grub e.g. [How can I load Ubuntu when all I have is Grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21342/how-can-i-load-ubuntu-when-all-i-have-is-grub)